# What code coverage tool/plugin can I use with SonarQube to cover the Xtend programming language?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, xtend, clover

I've googled high and low and found next to nothing on the topic, except this: http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2014/10/analyzing-xtend-code-with-sonarqube/

But that's 3 years old and references SonarQube 4.4.

When I check SonarQube's website at https://www.sonarqube.org/features/multi-languages/, I see no listing for the Xtend language.

Is there no way to get quality code coverage for Xtend?

Comment: it always depends, in which format your coverage is generated: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage -> this plugin is working with a generic format, if you can manage to bring it to this format, i am sure, you can somehow display it within sonarqube :D

Comment: That appears to be deprecated. It links to this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data

Comment: That appears to be deprecated. It links to this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data
As I'm new to SonarQube, I don't know what that means. Specifically, this sentence confuses me: "If your coverage engines' native output formats aren't supported by your language plugins, simply covert them to these formats."

It appears to me this only relates to output formats and does not make programming languages usable with SonarQube which are not officially supported via language plugin. Do correct me if I'm wrong, of course!

Comment: you simply asked how to cover your coverage - this is a way to cover coverage of a any language, it will just show the coverage and not analyse your code for issues -> it is pretty precisely the answer to your questions - if sonarqube does not support your language, you could use a generic test report format to show the coverage - and the steps mentioned in your blogpost seem to be still valid, as it uses simply the java plugin, - the question is, is xtend working the same way as in the blog

Comment: That appears to be deprecated. It links to this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/